# Asp.net: Page won't refresh after clicking dynamically generated Button controls

Tags: c#, asp.net

Clicking on any of the dynamically generated button controls does indeed call the b_Click          method and delete the given user, however, upon deleting the page does not reload the 'new' list of users.

```
        protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
          DbDB db = new DbDB();
          List<User> users = db.GetUsers().ExecuteTypedList<User>();

          foreach (User u in users)
          {
            Button b = new Button();
            b.Text = u.FirstName;
            b.Click += new EventHandler(b_Click);
            PlaceHolder1.Controls.Add(b);

          }

        }
       }

       void b_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
       {

          Button b = (Button)sender;
          DbDB.User.Delete(x => x.FirstName == b.Text);

       }
```

Comment: Is it calling b_click through an AJAX call? It's not performing a postback so you might have to add a refresh in javascript on an AJAX callback

Comment: Nope. No js other than what asp.net generates.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e) {
   LoadUsers();
}

void b_Click(object sender, EventArgs e) {      
   Button button = (Button)sender;
   string firstName = button.CommandArgument;  
   DbDB.User.Delete(x => x.FirstName == firstName);

   PlaceHolder1.Controls.Remove(button);
}

void LoadUsers() {  
   DbDB db = new DbDB();
   List<User> users = db.GetUsers().ExecuteTypedList<User>();

   foreach (User user in Users) {
      Button button = new Button();         
      button.CommandArgument = user.FirstName;  // normally the user "id" to identify the user.
      button.Text = user.FirstName;
      button.Click += new EventHandler(b_Click);
      PlaceHolder1.Controls.Add(button);
   }
}
```

Comment: that's wrong, dynamically generated controls should be recreated on postback. I can bet, Click event will not call in this case.

Answer (score 1):

That's because the Page_Load event is called before the Click event so when you're retrieving the list of users from the database in Page_Load the user is still in there.  As a quick solution you could move the code from Page_Load to PreRender event.

Have a look at this link for more info on the page life cycle: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms178472.aspx

Comment: If anything I would guess it to be PreInit since this, according to the docs in the link would be were dynamic controls should be created. However, it stiff does not work.

Answer (score 0):

You don't need to select users with every post-back. Also you don't need to create controls at runtime for this.

Following is an alternative way.

```
<asp:Repeater runat="server" ID="myRepeater">
    <ItemTemplate>
        <asp:Button runat="server" OnClick="Button_Click" Text='<%# DataBinder.Eval(Container.DataItem, "FirstName") %>' />
    </ItemTemplate>
</asp:Repeater>

protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    if (!this.IsPostBack)
    {
        // load users
        myRepeater.DataSource = users;
        myRepeater.DataBind();
    }
}

protected void Button_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    // delete user
    Button button = sender as Button;
    button.Visible = false;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Write your page_load body inside

```
if(!IsPostBack)
{
   ....
}
```

That should work.

Comment: Then move you method body to page_init method because page_load is not the place to create dynamic controls.